# jQuery - hide dropdown when clicking on other list-item

Tags: jquery, onclick, hide

I'm totally new to jQuery, so maybe this is an easy question, but i havent found a good answer till now. Maybe i havent even found the right keywords to search for...

By click on a list-item i display a dropdown-menu with the folllowing function:

```
$("li.dropdown").click(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu',this).css("display","block");
});
```

Works fine, but the dropdown keeps stayin. Now i want the dropdown-menu to hide again, when i

a) click on another li.dropdown (and then the new dropdown-menu must appear)
or
b) click somewhere else on the page

I get it to work when i click somewhere else on the page than li.dropdown, but not when i click on another li.dropdown (respectively then it doesnt show the "new" dropdown-menu of the newly clicked li).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include all your `HTML` and `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to be using `hide()` and `show()`

`$('.dropdown-menu',this).css("display","block");` is the same as `$('.dropdown-menu',this).show();` as it restores the selected element back to the **previous** display type. So if your element was set to display:inline-block before you .hide() it, it is set to that again when you .show() it.

As far as understanding what you need. We need a jsFiddle to tell exactly what you are aiming for. No one can answer this question with accuracy until you do so.